# other extension run as PHP on nginx

Tags: php, nginx

ok this my problem

i want .php ex change to .pys ex

i use software
- OpenBSD,
- Nginx 1.10,
- PHP70,
- PHP70 FastCGI

check my script nginx.conf

```
location ~ \.pys$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.pys)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

PHP Normal

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

i try

```
location ~ \.php|\.pys$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Not working

i know you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
location ~ \.(php|pys)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

You might have a look at this too. 
[How to Add Custom File Extension for PHP in Apache and Nginx](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/php-custom-file-extension/).

**Update:**
After visiting your link ending in `.pys` I got `Access denied` error and after trying it on my system I figured your problem might be caused by `security.limit_extension`. Please check [this thread](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-fpm-security-limit_extension-issue).

Comment: @grenz did you check that link too?

Comment: grenzpy.com/default.php or grenzpy.com/default.pys

Comment: @grenz I meant the link I added to my answer.

Comment: yes i visit 2 link after your answer, i edit nginx.conf and restart nginx, default.php work but pys just download file

Comment: hehehehe yes i see the link tutorial, but not work again, just download

Comment: @grenz I'm checking your url. It does not download anything. It just displays `Access denied` error.

Comment: okey work, maybe my pc cache, on my android is working Thank you Mr Hamed Momeni